# necesito cambiar el nombre de un elemento por otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

```
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

lo que necesito es que mediante una funcion poder cambiar "myslides" por "mySlides1"

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo. Saludos!

```js
//Obtengo el elemento
var elem =$("#input1");
//Muestro el nombre actual
console.log(elem.attr("name"))
//Asigno el nuevo nombre
elem.attr("name","nombre2");
//Verifico que el cambio se haya realizado.
console.log($("#input1").attr("name"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text" name="nombre1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el nombre de tu clase puede usar `TUDIV.className.replace(/ *\bmySlides\b/g, "mySlides1");` donde `TUDIV` es el elemento por id y el `replace()` lo uso para cambiar el nombre de la clase anterior en este caso `mySlides` por `mySlides1`, lo que tiene alrededor en el replace **/ *\b** y **\b/g** es una regla que se coloca para que funcione en todos los navegadores como Internet Explorer.

Te hice un ejemplo sencillo donde la clase `mySlides` tiene como borde rojo y cuando es cambiada la clase a `mySlides1` cambia a azul:

```js
document.getElementById("cambiar-clase").addEventListener("click", function() {

  slides = document.getElementById("div");
  slides.className = slides.className.replace(/ *\bmySlides\b/g, "mySlides1");

});
```

```css
.mySlides{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:50px;
}

.mySlides1{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="cambiar-clase">Cambiar nombre de clase</button>

<div id="div" class="mySlides"><div>
```

Comment: Ahora que me doy cuenta, parece que esta mal redactada la pregunta. Yo me guié del titulo y le explique como cambiar el **NOMBRE** de un elemento, osea el **atributo "name"**. De todos modos cualquiera de las 2 respuestas debería servirle.

Comment: Si esta mal redactada y me ha pasado varias veces que doy respuesta y cuando leo bien el enunciado es otra cosa.